# Не приходит почта в связку Postfix+Dovecot

Tags: email, smtp, postfix, dovecot

Я использую postfix, dovecot, roundcube для почтового сервера, все работает нормально, за исключением того, что я не могу получать почту из внешнего источника. Я могу отправлять письма локальному и внешнему источнику.

Во время настройки следовал руководству с [blog.bissquit.com](http://blog.bissquit.com/unix/debian/nastrojka-postfix/).

При отправке почты из внешнего источника, спустя некоторое время, приходит ошибка

```
Final-Recipient: rfc822; info@domain.ru
Action: delayed
Status: 4.4.1
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; The recipient server did not accept our requests to connect. Learn more at https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7720
 [mail.domain.ru. ipv6 adress: generic::failed_precondition: connect error (0): error]
 [mail.domain.ru. ipv4 adress: generic::failed_precondition: connect error (0): error]
```

Postfix main.conf

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
myorigin = $mydomain

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html -- default to 2 on
# fresh installs.
compatibility_level = 2

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_tls_security_level = may

smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
mydomain = domain.ru
myhostname = mail.domain.ru
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
mydestination = localhost.$mydomain, localhost, localhost.localdomain
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
home_mailbox = Maildir/
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all

virtual_mailbox_base = /var/vmail
virtual_mailbox_domains =
 proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_domains_maps.cf
virtual_alias_maps =
 proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf,
 proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_alias_domain_maps.cf,
 proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_alias_domain_catchall_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps =
 proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_mailbox_maps.cf,
 proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_alias_domain_mailbox_maps.cf
```

Dovecot config

```
#-------------------dovecot.conf- - http://www.dovecot.org/doc/dovecot-example.conf
protocols = imap pop3

#-------------------10-auth.conf- - http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Authentication
disable_plaintext_auth = yes
auth_mechanisms = plain login

#-------------------10-logging.conf- - http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Logging
log_path = /var/log/dovecot.log
info_log_path = /var/log/dovecot-info.log
debug_log_path = /var/log/dovecot-debug.log
auth_verbose = yes
auth_debug = yes
auth_debug_passwords = yes
mail_debug = yes
auth_verbose_passwords = sha1
verbose_ssl = yes

#-------------------10-mail.conf- - http://wiki.dovecot.org/MailLocation
mail_location = maildir:/var/vmail/%d/%n
mail_uid = 5000
mail_gid = 5000
mail_privileged_group = vmail

#-------------------10-master.conf- - http://wiki.dovecot.org/Services
service auth {
 unix_listener auth-userdb {
 mode = 0600
 user = vmail
 group = vmail
 }
 unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
 mode = 0666
 user = postfix
 group = postfix
 }
}
service imap-login {
 inet_listener imap {
 }
 inet_listener imaps {
 }
}
service pop3-login {
 inet_listener pop3 {
 }
 inet_listener pop3s {
 }
}

#-------------------10-ssl.conf- - http://wiki.dovecot.org/SSL/DovecotConfiguration
ssl = yes
ssl_cert = </etc/dovecot/dovecot.pem
ssl_key = </etc/dovecot/private/dovecot.pem

#-------------------15-lda.conf- - http://wiki.dovecot.org/LDA
protocol lda {
}

#-------------------15-mailboxes.conf- - http://wiki2.dovecot.org/MailboxSettings
namespace inbox {
 inbox = yes
 mailbox Drafts {
 special_use = \Drafts
 auto = subscribe
 }
 mailbox Junk {
 special_use = \Junk
 auto = subscribe
 }
 mailbox Trash {
 special_use = \Trash
 auto = subscribe
 }
 mailbox Sent {
 special_use = \Sent
 auto = subscribe
 }
}

#-------------------90-plugin.conf- - http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Plugins
plugin {
}

#-------------------auth-sql.conf.ext- - http://wiki2.dovecot.org/AuthDatabase/SQL
userdb {
 driver = sql
 args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf
}
passdb {
 driver = sql
 args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf
}
```

Проверка SMTP порта

```
root@example:~# netstat -pel | grep smtp
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:smtp            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      root       845985     28651/master
tcp6       0      0 [::]:smtp               [::]:*                  LISTEN      root       845986     28651/master
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     846084   28651/master         private/bsmtp
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     845989   28651/master         private/smtpd
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     846042   28651/master         private/smtp
```

Проверка 25 порта

```
root@example:~# netstat -plnt |grep :25
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      28651/master
tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::*                    LISTEN      28651/master
```

В правилах iptables так же есть несколько других портов

```
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:25
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:110
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:143
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:465
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:587
```

Проверка dig MX

```
root@example:~# dig mx domain.ru

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Debian <<>> mx domain.ru
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 54832
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;domain.ru.                 IN      MX

;; ANSWER SECTION:
domain.ru.          3600    IN      MX      10 mail.domain.ru.

;; Query time: 51 msec
;; SERVER: 77.88.8.8#53(77.88.8.8)
;; WHEN: Tue Jul 25 16:52:37 MSK 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 52
```

Подскажите, почему я не могу получить почту от внешнего источника?
Спасибо.

Comment: А почему на правиле iptables в начале нули, похоже до вашего правила управление никогда не доходило (возможно пакеты отвергали предыдущие правила). попробуйте зайти телнетом на свой 25 порт снаружи и убедится, что он выдает приглашение и реагирует хотя бы на команду HELO

Comment: @Mike, да вроде бы правила нормально работают. Во всяком случае я получил на **telnet domain.ru 25**:
`220 mail.domain.ru ESMTP Postfix (Debian/GNU)
HELO mail.domain.ru
250 mail.domain.ru`

Comment: Вы этот telnet запускали надеюсь, откуда то снаружи, не с самой машины... Тогда вам остается только запустить `tcpdump -n -i eth0 port 25`, попробовать отправить себе почту и посмотреть есть ли обращения. И кстати из dig не ясно, определен ли в зоне ip для имени mail.domain.ru

Comment: @Mike, конечно со стороны. :)
tcpdump засыпает ответами при отправки письма из вне. Они все на IP6 и письма в webmail нет. Может ли быть проблема с ipv6 или вообще на стороне Roundcube?

Comment: Руками письмо себе отправьте через telnet и посмотрите что отвечает ваш почтовик. `HELO test@domain.com / MAIL FROM: abc@test.com / RCPT TO: you@domain.com / DATA / текст письма / .` (под косыми имеется ввиду новая строка, в RCPT пишите ваш ящик на который отправляете). И еще не помешало бы заглянуть в логи. И roundcube тут вообще не причем, потому что он клиент для чтения почты, к MTA он не имеет никакого отношения

Comment: @Mike, хм, судя по логу `Jul 25 17:50:00 domain postfix/qmgr[28653]: 40C4B5F730: from=<mymail@gmail.com>, size=592, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jul 25 17:50:00 domain postfix/virtual[29602]: warning: recipient info@domain.ru: not found in virtual_uid_maps` письмо приходит в очередь, но не находится в базе информации куда его положить. Или я не правильно понял эти строчки?

Comment: Да, вы правильно поняли. Смотрите настройки постфикса

Comment: @Mike, большое спасибо за наводку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение оказалось достаточно простым. Всего лишь нужно было указать в конфиге Postfix

```
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
```